# Establishing SSH connection using Python

Tags: python, ssh, jupyter, paramiko

This is the first time I'm asking a question on stackoverflow, so do inform me if I should ask questions differently or provide additional data.

I have an ssh command that I run on my command prompt to connect to postgreSQL server

```
ssh -L 5433:<host>:5432 -i <public_key> <username>@<IP address> -p 1024 -N
```

I try run the same through a python script, when I run it using

```
os.system("ssh -L 5433:<host>:5432 -i <public_key> <username>@<IP address> -p 1024 -N")
conn1 = None
conn1 = psycopg2.connect(dbname="db",user="username",
host="localhost", password="xxxx",port="5433")
```

It throws me the following error,

> could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
> Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
> TCP/IP connections on port 5433?

I have tried using paramiko to connect to the same, but I'm unable to translate the command line that I have to all the parameters required, for example, I don't understand port1:xxx:port2 and how to implement that in paramiko, the same goes for the public key. Given below is the code I use for that,

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('<hostname>', username='<username>, key_filename='<public_key>')
```

I've looked through many documentations but can't find a solution to the same. Any help is massively appreciated.